# Apply different css style to two same h4 tag which has same class name

Tags: html, css

I am having two h4 tags with same classs name. I want to change the color of second h4 tag value. But the color applying to the 1st tag also. I don't know how to differentiate the 1st tag from the second one

`<h4 _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-center vertical-spacing-5">Job Cart1</h4>`

```
<h4 _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-center vertical-spacing-5">Job Cart2</h4>
```

I want to change the color of the text only using css. I cant' add or change anything in html side

Comment: You can use a sibbling selector : `.text-center.vertical-spacing-5 {color:yellow} .text-center.vertical-spacing-5 ~ .text-center.vertical-spacing-5 {color:red} `

Comment: @G-Cyr — Only if they are sibblings

Comment: As commented, are they siblings?

Comment: I can't use sibling selectors. They are not siblings. both are in different div

Comment: but the parent are sibblings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the elements are identical, you can only distinguish between them describing their relationships with *other elements* using [combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#combinators) and/or [structural pseudo-classes](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#structural-pseudos).

Since these depend on the position of the other elements DOM structure, the specifics of how you do this depends on what that DOM structure is.

For example, if the structure was something like this:

```css
h4 {
  color: red;
}

section+section h4 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <section>
    <h4 _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-center vertical-spacing-5">Job Cart1</h4>
    <p>Ipsum…</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h4 _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-center vertical-spacing-5">Job Cart1</h4>
    <p>Ipsum…</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `h4.vertical-spacing-5:nth-of-type(2)`

```css
h4.vertical-spacing-5:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h4 _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-center vertical-spacing-5">Job Cart1</h4>

<h4 _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-center vertical-spacing-5">Job Cart2</h4>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
h4.text-center:nth-child(2)
        {
          color: red;
        }
```

Comment: Please don't write code-only answers, try to explain what you're doing.

Comment: The question is tagged with `html` and `css`, not `jquery`, so if you want to provide with an non-tagged tech, ask first if that is an option